# I think i need a SQL Loop for calculation

Tags: sql, loops

Alright so im triying to figure this out and not having alot of success. I managed to rank the order service jobs are done by technican and day. Im trying to calculate travel time. Logically to do this i need to take the onsite date from job order=2 and subtract it from the clear date of job order=1. Then continue for that employees remaining jobs for that day. I wanna do this for each day for each employee.
Job order is a dense rank partitioned by employee number and ordered by onsite data.

here is the basic data layout
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg3Tg.png)

Comment: Please edit the question, add table definition, example data, and expected output, and tag question with DB vendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot test the statement, because I have no SQL server installed right now. But the following statement should give you what you need.

```
SELECT (NextOrder.onsite_date - PreviousOrder.clear_date) AS TravelTime
FROM dbo.employee as PreviousOrder
INNER JOIN dbo.employee as NextOrder
    ON PreviousOrder.emp_no = NextOrder.emp_no
    AND PreviousOrder.JobOrder + 1 = NextOrder.JobOrder
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, PreviousOrder.clear_date) = DATEPART(YEAR, NextOrder.onsite_date)
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, PreviousOrder.clear_date) = DATEPART(MONTH, NextOrder.onsite_date)
    AND DATEPART(DAY, PreviousOrder.clear_date) = DATEPART(DAY, NextOrder.onsite_date)
```

Maybe you can change the DATEPART comparisons with

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, PreviousOrder.clear_date, NextOrder.onsite_date) = 0
```